# Grouped UITableView, with no outlines for UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

I want to create different custom items for a small grouped table of 4-5 rows.  I want to use a TableView since it has the layout and sizing already there.  Is there a way to remove the lines between each row?  I don't want it to look like a tableView and with the row lines it definitely does.  I want it to look just like a rounded rect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I understood you correctly.

tbl.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

This will result in a table that looks something like-

[image]